# How to verify account by passing token to the email and user will enter it

Tags: django

In django when some one signup for new account, he will be sent an email with an activation link.

One has to click on the activation link sent to them to activate their account. This i was able to achieve using Django.

Presently I am developing a mobile app.

I feel instead of asking them to click on an activation link, i want them to enter some code inside the app.

The code will be sent to their email.

So how to verify the account by passing token and later user will enter it.

Answer (score 0):

1)Extend the user model with a token field. 
2)Generate a random short value in that field
3)Edit registration email template to include this token
4)Create an API endpoint to listen for POST and wait for a match of USERNAME+TOKEN